# Avoid IntelliJ evaluating lazy list

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I have implemented an implementation of `java.util.List<T>` that lazily calculates its elements.

It works fine, except that when I use IntelliJ to debug the code, it starts evaluating the entire list. The IntelliJ debugger is set to only show the first 100 elements of the list, but the debugger evaluates the entire list anyway.

Can I change an IntelliJ setting, place an annotation, derive from a different class or something to change this behavior?

Here is a simpler class that demonstrates the problem:

```
public class LazyList extends AbstractList<Integer> {
    @Override
    public Integer get(int index) {
        // If I place a breakpoint on the next line, IntelliJ starts evaluating 
        // the entire list.
        if (index > 10000) {
            System.out.println("Calling slow method");
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return 100000;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LazyList list = new LazyList();
        System.out.println(list.get(100));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can uncheck the checkbox in File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Debugger -> Enable auto expression in Variables view.

Comment: Sorry, no, that does not work. Even with that checkmark removed, IntelliJ still evaluates the entire list. Looks like it is calling `toArray()`.